# how to get the list of channels where a bot is admin using pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I'm looking for a way to identify channels where a Telegram bot acts as an admin. My goal is to get a list of these channels to check if the bot has been added to any of them.

I am currently using the Pyrogram framework to interact with the various Telegram APIs. However, I am facing a particular challenge: I have not been able to find any clues or methods in the documentation that would allow me to identify the channels in which a Telegram bot acts as administrator. This information is essential for my project, as I need to create a complete list of these channels in order to accurately check and ensure that the bot has been added as an admin on each of them.

I have extensively reviewed the documentation provided by Pyrogram and have done additional searches in external sources, but so far, I have not found a suitable solution for my problem. If you have any suggestions, advice or prior knowledge on how to approach this particular challenge with Pyrogram or any other Telegram related tools, I would be very grateful for your guidance. My ultimate goal is to be able to carry out this task efficiently and accurately within the framework of my ongoing project.